# .htaccess Config causing Google Analytics conversions to fail

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, google-analytics

I have setup my .htaccess to add a trailing slash to each URL, but having done this I can see that my Google Analytics conversions (goal type is 'Destination') do not work.

The page I'm trying to track is:

```
/thank-you/contact/
```

And the trailing slash gets added by .htaccess if not already there. In GA I have told it to track 'Begins with' /thank-you/contact, 'Equals /thank-you/contact/' etc. Nothing works.

If I comment out the .htaccess rule that adds the trailing slash the conversion tracking immediately starts working again. Have I got some kind of bad config in my .htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine On

# add trailing slash
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.co.uk/$1/ [L,R=301]

#remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

#remove index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: which page have you setted as destination in ga? `/thank-you/contact/` or `/thank-you/contact` ?

Comment: I have tried both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try regular expression condition with goal settings

```
thank-you\/contact.*
```

trailing `.*` would match or zero and unlimited characters